# Is it possible to reinitialise (or dispose) a Blazor (server side app's) scoped service programatically on a condition?

Tags: c#, razor, service, scope, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server side app, where I store the user specific variables in a scoped service. The service is just containing user specific variables, that should be retentive as long as the user is logged in.

But I want that these variables should be also reinitialized (set to their default values) when the user is still logged in but there is a special condition in my code (For example on a button click) in a razor page.

Is it possible to reinitialize a Blazor server side app's scoped service?

Razor code

```
 @inject VARService VARService
 <button @onclick="Reinitialise">Reinitialise</button>
 private void Reinitialise()
  {
    // Some code for initilising the scoped service (VARService)
  }
```

Scoped service

```
public class VARService
{
  public int user_varibale1=0;
  public int user_varibale2=0;
  public float user_varibale3=1.25;
  public string user_varibale4="abc";
  // lots of user_variables     

 }
```

Comment: Hint: classes can have methods.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Thank you for the hint. But as I have recently changed from industrial automation sector to software developement, I couldn't get what you mean exactly. Could you explain very short?

Comment: Add a method, `void ResetValues`, and set all your variable values there.  Then call that Method whenever you want the values reset.